# Mathematical Modelling for Textual definition

Tags: mathematical-modeling

If x in Z {x, y, e} is identified as same/identical with any element fn in F{f1,f2, f4...fn} or un of an E{u1,u2,...un}, then the y in Z and e in Z will be having influence relationship with identical fn in F or un in E.

I want a nice representation of above description.
Thank you in advance

Comment: What is $Z\{x,y,e\}$ etc. even supposed to mean? And what could an influence relationship be?

Comment: it means that x, y, and e are element of Z.

Comment: The influence relationship means when event y or event e occurs they impact on un or fn of E and F respectively. Given that x is identical/same with any un or fn.

Comment: Oh , so you mean $Z=\{x,y,e\}$? And by definition of "identical", don't yo merely want to state that $y$ and $e$ impact $x$?

Comment: yes you are right,y and e impact on x and if fn or/and un are found similar with x, then y and e will also be having impact on fn and un.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen